# Android refactor small method to return String from object breaks

Tags: android, pojo

So I have a class that has

```
String city, state;
public String getCity() {return city;} public String getState(){get state;}
```

if I change this class around where city and state are replaced with a Class City which contains the two strings name and state to be

```
City city;
public String getCity() { return city.getName();}
public String getState() {return city.getState();}
```

it stops working.  It just doesn't transfer to my next intent after the splash screen, no errors.  Does android use the constructor? or use some kind of direct field access instead of the getters that I'm not aware of?

thanks!

it seems so dumb I don't get it.  I don't get any errors either.

The class (Tour) these fields are in, as well as the City class are the simplest of pojos I use to display in a list view. I load the List in a splash screen, then pass off an intent to the Activity with the list view of them. When city and state are both string variables in Tour it works. When I replace city and state with Class City which has name and state String member variables the next intent never shows. It just sits on the splash screen. That is the only change.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, TourListActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(TourList.class.getCanonicalName(), tours);
startActivity(intent); //this line starts but nothing else is ever called
```

yeah.  If I remove logcat filters I get this after my last app specific log message

```
02-12 20:28:43.975    826-31520/? W/ContextImpl﹕ Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1510 com.android.server.InputMethodManagerService$4.run:2772 java.lang.Thread.run:841 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack>
```

but as I read it that's just anything really.  but how would that simple pojo change cause that?

Comment: There's not enough info here, like what 'stops working' means more specifically in terms of logs, errors, etc, what `City` is. No, Android does not use any different magic Java.

Comment: The class (Tour) these fields are in, as well as the City class are the simplest of pojos I use to display in a list view.  I load the List<Tour> in a splash screen, then pass off an intent to the Activity with the list view of them.  When city and state are both string variables in Tour it works. When I replace city and state with Class City which has name and state String member variables the next intent never shows.  It just sits on the splash screen.  That is the only change.

I don't know what else to say, it seems so dumb.

Comment: **"I don't get any errors either."** : Are you sure? Have you looked at logcat?

Comment: yeah.  If I remove logcat filters I get

Comment: In your line of code:
`intent.putExtra(TourList.class.getCanonicalName(), tours);`, what is 'tours' ? Is it a Parcelable or at least a Serializable ?

Comment: The City class wasn't serializable.  Adding that fixed everything.  Thanks for your time everyone.

Answer (score 0):

My City class didn't implement Serializable.  Every class you pass with an Intent must implement java.io.Serializable